# How to make a call on static method with queue

Tags: java, queue, call

// I want to pass [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] into mystery2
//

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    mystery2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // need help here
}

public static void mystery2(Queue<Integer> q) {    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass like this..

```
mystery2(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

LinkedList implements Queue interface and has the Constructor that takes the Collection as an constructor argument.

Hope this helps. Cheers !!!

Comment: Or add a method `public static void mystery2(Integer... q) { return mystery2(new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(q)); }`. (`LinkedList` is generally a bad idea - array structures should be your default.)